# Ant: Create tar without path information?

Tags: java, ant, jar, tar

**Update**:  I am using Ant 1.8.1 on Windows XP.

I am trying to write an Ant master build file for multiple projects.  I can successfully create a jar for each project, and I want to package all of these jars into a single tar.gz file.  Each jar file is located within the bin subdirectory of its respective project, but this path could be changed in the future.  I've tried something like this:

```
<tar destfile="foo.tar.gz" compression="gzip" >
   <tarfileset dir=".">
      <include name="**/*.jar" />
   </tarfileset>
</tar>
```

...which kind of works.  The only problem is that it maintains the directory structure within the jar.  I want a flat file.  So instead of:

```
foo.tar.gz
   project1
      bin
         project1.jar
   project2
      bin
         project2.jar
etc...
```

I need:

```
foo.tar.gz
   project1.jar
   project2.jar
```

I attempted to use Ant's copy task to copy these jar files to a temporary directory and then tar them from there.  However, the copy operation replicates paths within the target directory. So, same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're almost there, having assembled a flattened directory of your files. What remains is to get rid of the `tarfileset` element, which is there specifically for preserving/inserting structure. I think `tar` and `zip` tasks work fine with embedded `fileset` elements.

The documentation bears me out on this - up until 1.7 `fileset` was the embedded resource element that could be used in place of `tarfileset`.

Come to think of it, I think that once you switch to `fileset`, you may no longer need to temp-copy your files for flattening.

---

**EDIT:**

I just built and ran this buildfile:

```
<project name="tartest" default="teer">
   <target name="teer">
      <tar destfile="tartest.tar">
     <fileset dir="../Downloads" includes="*.ico *.gif"/>
      </tar>
   </target>
</project>
```

and there was no trace of the original directory in the archive:

```
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            3487 2009-12-28 20:04 actor075_thumb.gif
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            1456 2010-06-16 10:57 bea-logo.gif
-rw-r--r-- 0/0           23800 2010-06-16 09:22 ejb1.gif
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            1406 2010-05-15 10:40 favicon-beta.ico
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            1406 2010-05-15 10:25 favicon-clown.ico
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            1406 2008-12-06 01:08 favicon.ico
```

Also, `tar -xvf tartest.tar` dumped the tarred files in my current directory.

So... what are you doing differently that is causing different results for you?

---

**EDIT 2:**

More insight gained from re-reading your question. I'd completely sidestepped the problem of source paths generated by `**/*` wildcards.

Since you're already considering copying those jar files to a temporary directory, all that's missing is to use the `flatten` attribute on the `copy` task. That should fix you up.

Comment: I tried switching to fileset instead of tarfileset, but I had the same results.

Comment: I apologize for all the irrelevant advice and comments so far. I believe my 2nd update now has the info you need.

Comment: Thanks!  Flatten worked.  I copied all jar files to a temporary directory using <copy todir="temp" flatten="true"> and tarred them from there.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to work with [zipFileSet](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/zipfileset.html) to accomplish this.  It Allows you to control the overall structure providing your own prefix (or no prefix).

```
<zip destfile="${dist}/product.zip">
    <zipfileset dir="bin/project1.jar" prefix="any/fake/path/you/want"/>
    <zipfileset dir="bin/project2.jar" prefix="any/fake/path/you/want"/>
    <zipfileset dir="some/other/path/project3.jar" prefix="any/fake/path/you/want"/>
</zip>
```

Will result in:

```
any/fake/path/you/want/project1.jar
any/fake/path/you/want/project2.jar
any/fake/path/you/want/project3.jar
```

Comment: I have to use a wildcard like "**/*.jar" because I have multiple subprojects (and more to be added in the future).  I need to make it generic rather than manually adding every single one to the build file.  I tried to create a zip file, which is almost identical to the original tar version I put above.  It had the same result.

I tried using the prefix attribute, but it merely appends the relative path of the file to the prefix I provide.  E.g. prefix="test/out/" would create files within the archive with paths like "test/out/project1/bin/project1.tar" and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at Ant's [`flattenmapper`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html).

Comment: I looked at that too, but in some places ant's documentation is too cryptic to help in using the features. I wasn't able to fathom how to use a `flattenmapper` within a `tar` task so I opted for the simpler solution of using the `flatten` attribute of `copy`. Are you aware of more helpful documentation on ant tasks?

Comment: I forgot, this is how it SHOULD work, but for some reason Ant doesn't allow you to use mappers with the `tar` task.  You end up having to construct the files in roughly the same layout you need beforehand.